# Stop KnockoutJS from using jQuery.tmpl

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

I'm adding Knockout to specific section of a large application. Other parts make use of jQuery Templates (and it's embeded in a base JS file), so it's on the global jQuery object and I cannot remove it.

I'm running into the following error message when I use a `foreach` binding in a template:

```
This template engine does not support the 'foreach' binding within its templates
```

It seems this is a problem when using the jQuery Template engine with Knockout.
Is there any way to make Knockout use its default template engine rather than jQuery Templates?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ko.setTemplateEngine(new ko.nativeTemplateEngine());` before calling `ko.applyBindings`.

Comment: Once again, you save the day. Thanks!

Comment: @NP Niemeyer I am very curious how this syntax is behaving. At first glance, I didn't expect the usage of a `new` keyword to work when calling the function `ko.nativeTemplateEngine()`. I tried running the function just by itself and you get nothing but then if you add the `new` keyword, it is, in fact, creating a new object. Mind providing some insight here?

Comment: @FeistyMango - `ko.nativeTemplateEngine` is a constructor function. When you call it with `new`, the value of `this` is set to a new instance (object) that has the correct prototype.